# Batch Extract pathdir from a variable

Tags: batch-file, split, dos

if I have this situation:

```
C:\Users\l72\Desktop\fs.cfg
C:\Users\s80\Desktop\tt.cfg
C:\Users\r88\Desktop\kj.cfg
```

and each entire path is setted to a variable

```
set dir1=C:\Users\l72\Desktop\fs.cfg
.
.
.
```

how can I extract only the second field(l72,s80,r88)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=3delims=\" %%i in ("%dir1%") do echo %%i
```

is a way to extract the third token from the string contained in the environment variable `dir1` when the string is tokenised using `\` as a delimiter.

Comment: On SO we generally do not accept 1 line code only answers as sufficient.  Could you please elaborate on your answer?